# Parsing objects out of PDF, objects with byte streams are ignored for some reason?

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing, bytestream

My current assignment includes taking all of the objects out of the pdf file and then using the parsed out objects. But there is an issue that I have noticed where some of the stream objects are being flat out skipped over by my code.

I am completely confused and hoping someone can help indicate what is going wrong here.

*Here is the main parsing code.*

```
    void parseRawPDFFile() {
        //Transform the bytes obtained from the file into a byte character sequence. This byte character sequence
        //object is what allows us to use it in regex.
        ByteCharSequence byteCharSequence = new ByteCharSequence(bytesFromFile.toByteArray());
        byteCharSequence.getStringFromData();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(SINGLE_OBJECT_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(byteCharSequence);

        //While we have a match (apparently only one match exists at a time) keep looping over the list.
        //When a match is found, get the starting and ending indices and manually cut these out char by char
        //and assemble them into a new "ByteArrayOutputStream".
        int counterOfDoom = 1;
        while (matcher.find() ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream cutOutArray = cutOutByteArrayOutputStreamFromOriginal(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(cutOutArray);
                //At this point we have cut out the object and can now send it for processing.
               createPDFObject(cutOutArray);

                System.out.println(counterOfDoom);
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
                counterOfDoom++;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Here is the code for the ByteCharSequence*
(Credits for the core of this code here: http://blog.sarah-happy.ca/2013/01/java-regular-expression-on-byte-array.html)

```
public class ByteCharSequence implements CharSequence {

    private final byte[] data;
    private final int length;
    private final int offset;

    public ByteCharSequence(byte[] data) {
        this(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    public ByteCharSequence(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
        this.data = data;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return this.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return (char) (data[offset + index] & 0xff);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return new ByteCharSequence(data, offset + start, end - start);
    }

    /**
     * Get the string from the ByteCharSequence data.
     * @return
     */
    public String getStringFromData() {
        //Load it into the method I know works to convert it to a string... Optimized? Probably not at all.
        //But it works...
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (byte individualByte: data
             ) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(individualByte);
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }
}
```

*The pdf data that I am processing at present:*

```
10 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1040>>stream
(Bunch of bytes)
endstream
endobj


12 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 2574/N 3>>stream
(Bunch of bytes)
endstream
endobj
```

*Some information that I was trying to look into.*

1: From what I understand there should be no limitation on how much can be fit into the data structures. So size shouldn't be an issue????

Comment: Check your regex pattern

Comment: @Dummy checked over my regex in regexer and sadly it seems like it should work for that :( It did highlight the one test object I put in that isn't going though unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard and easy when debugging regex, it's easy because when it doesn't match where you think it should, you know you have a bug in your pattern, it's hard because you dont know why you have the bug 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [DOTALL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to the pattern compile call so that your pattern matches newline characters =)